# What is the difference between `Area_2D`, `Area_3D`, and `Volume` in surface volume calculation?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, 3d, arcscene, volume, subsurface

I want to know the meaning of output text files of surface volume dialog box. For example, the file contains headers and numbers as below:

```
Dataset, Plane_Height, Reference, Z_Factor, Area_2D, Area_3D, Volume. 
raster_to_tin, 50,00, BELOW, 1,000000, 385387,1505728, 414338,45311207, 4544086,3828428
```

What is the difference between `Area_2D`, `Area_3D`, and `Volume`?

Comment: You seem to be asking a near identical question for the third time. If there is an aspect that remains unanswered then I recommend that you edit this question to focus on just that aspect.

Answer (score 2):

All the answers are found in the ArcGIS resource site.
Here's the [Surface Volume tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Surface_Volume/00q900000027000000/), and a more elaborate help regarding [your questions](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/How_Surface_Volume_works/00q900000037000000/).

Comment: This could be considered a link only answer. It is better to at least summarize the information in your answer rather than only provide links which may break in the future. I would also suggest [this page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Find_the_volume_contained_in_a_surface/00q900000051000000/) of that section as a better explanation to answer the actual question.